# JWPlayer Ad Skipping button permanent

Tags: jwplayer, jwplayer6, jwplayer7

I have been reading through the JWPlayer ad skipping doc https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1433818-configuring-ad-skipping and I know you can configure a countdown for the skip button like this:

advertising: {
  client: "vast",
  skipoffset:5,
  tag: "//adserver.com/vastResponse.xml"
}

But is there any way to leave the skip button permanent? without any countdown, just stick there the whole time from the beginning.

Anyway I found a way to do it setting a 0 value as a string, like this:

advertising: {
  client: "vast",
  skipoffset: "0",
  tag: "//adserver.com/vastResponse.xml"
}

But, well, is this intended? is this the way to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until a better solution I will leave here a working one as I said in the question.

Setting the skippfoset as a "0" string will do the trick:

```
advertising: { client: "vast", skipoffset: "0",
tag: "//adserver.com/vastResponse.xml" }
```